# How to run Kivy Application from individual Python Module?

Tags: python, kivy

I am having the following Kivy Application, embedded into a Python Module called `TouchInterface` (the code was copied from the coding guide on the Kivy Webpage):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()
```

When running the Application like this:

```
if __name__ = '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Kivy starts up and runs the basic application.

But instead of running it from CLI or as the main Entry Point to my Application I want the Kivy app to be embedded in a separate Module - like I mentioned above - and want to start this Module from a main entry point, like this:

```
from TouchInterface import MyApp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Point where I start up other Modules in future ...
    MyApp().run()
```

This however leads to a strange bug. When I start the Python Script where the Kivy Application is loaded as a Module, I get the following error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-07-04_36.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers:  (img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get any Image provider, abort.
```

And I absolutely have no clue what is going on here.

Comment: In which module you call `MyApp().run()` shouldn't matter. Are you sure you are using a python that has access to an image provider? Your error message indicates a problem in the kivy installation.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your specific problem is caused by running from a different module, but to answer the question in the title here's a sample which should work.

Given a project setup like so:

```
runner.py
example
  - assets
      - image.png
  - __init__.py
  - example.py
  - example.kv
```

#### runner.py:

```
from example import run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

#### **init**.py:

```
from .example import run
```

#### example.py:

```
from kivy.app import App

class ExampleApp(App):
    kv_file: 'example/example.kv'

def run():
    ExampleApp().run()
```

#### example.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import kivy kivy
#:import win kivy.core.window

FloatLayout:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1,
        Rectangle:
            source: 'example/assets/image.png'
            size: self.size
```

You should be able to run `python runner.py` without any issues. The sample will display a FloatLayout with the image from `example/assets/image.py` as the background.

The thing that caught me out when I was trying to get this to work is that the references to the kv file seem to be relative to the location of your `main`, rather than the location of the app. This is why you need to specify `kv_file:` in the app definition, rather than relying on the fact that they're in the same directory and have the same name.

Likewise, locations *within* the kv file are relative to `main`, and not the file - this is why the image source is 'example/assets/image.png` and not 'assets/image.png'